# backtracking in javascript, can't update global variable

Tags: javascript, parameters, global-variables, recursive-backtracking

I'm trying to solve problem of [day 9 of the advent of code](http://adventofcode.com/day/9) in javascript.

I'm using backtracking for getting all possible routes and then calculate the cost of each one.

I'm used to do backtracking in languages like PHP and C++, but never did in JS, so I've found thanks to google that you can't pass a mutable parameter like the **&** parameters in both PHP and C++.

My intent is to assign the **bestRoute** variable to the best route because that is the solution of the problem.

But when I do that, using return in some sites, I get an undefined variable error like this:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < neighborsArray.length ; i++) {
                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at getCostInNeighbors (/home/freinn/librosjavascript/advent_of_code/day9.js:117:40)
        at calculateCost (/home/freinn/librosjavascript/advent_of_code/day9.js:110:17)
```

Here is my current code, that does not work and prints bestRoute like the first defined.

```
"use strict";

function clone(obj) {
    // Handle the 3 simple types, and null or undefined
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;

    // Handle Date
    if (obj instanceof Date) {
        var copy = new Date();
        copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Array
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        var copy = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
            copy[i] = clone(obj[i]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Object
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        var copy = {};
        for (var attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
                copy[attr] = clone(obj[attr]);
            }
        }
        return copy;
    }

    throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
}

function generateGraphAsArray(input) {
    var lines = input.split("\n");
    var getFromTo = /(.*?) to (.*?) = (\d+)/;
    var graph = {};
    var matches = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < lines.length ; i++) {
        matches = getFromTo.exec(lines[i]);
        // console.log(matches[1], matches[2], matches[3]);

        var obj = {};
        obj['to'] = matches[2];
        obj['cost'] = matches[3];
        var clonated = clone(obj);

        if (!(matches[1] in graph)) {
            graph[matches[1]] = [];
        }

        graph[matches[1]].push(clonated);

        if (!(matches[2] in graph)) {
            graph[matches[2]] = [];
        }

        obj['to'] = matches[1];
        clonated = clone(obj);
        graph[matches[2]].push(clonated);
    }

    var keys = Object.keys(graph);
    var graphArray = [];
    var nodeList;

    // recuerda: en JS la funcion que no devuelve nada, devuelve algo, undefined
    // si no ponemos return en la funcion del map, dara undefined
    for (var prop in graph) {
        // esto es una clausura sana para poder usar keys
        nodeList = graph[prop].map(function(obj) {
            return nodeObjectToArray(keys, obj);
        });
        graphArray.push(nodeList);
    }

    return graphArray;
}

function nodeObjectToArray(keys, obj) {
    var array = new Array(keys.indexOf(obj.to), Number(obj.cost));
    return array;
}

function generateAllRoutes(numberOfNodes, graphArray) {
    var routes = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < numberOfNodes; i++) {
        var array = [i]
        routes.push(array);
    }

    var bestRoute = generateRangeWithoutUsed([], numberOfNodes);
    for (var i = 0 ; i < routes.length; i++) {
        bestRoute = generateRoutes(routes[i], numberOfNodes, bestRoute, graphArray);
    }

    console.log(bestRoute, calculateCost(bestRoute, graphArray));
}

function calculateCost(route, graphArray) {
    var limit = graphArray.length - 1;
    var cost = 0;

    for (var i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++) {
        cost += getCostInNeighbors(graphArray[route[i]], route[i+1]);
    }

    return cost;
}

function getCostInNeighbors(neighborsArray, neighbour) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < neighborsArray.length ; i++) {
        if (neighborsArray[i][0] == neighbour) {
            return neighborsArray[i][1];
        }
    }
}

function generateRoutes(currentRoute, numberOfNodes, bestRoute, graphArray) {
    if (currentRoute.length == numberOfNodes) {
        var currentRouteCost = calculateCost(currentRoute, graphArray);

        console.log(currentRouteCost);

        if (currentRouteCost < calculateCost(bestRoute, graphArray)) {
            return currentRoute;
        } else {
            return bestRoute;
        }
    } else {
        var possibleNextNodes = generateRangeWithoutUsed(currentRoute, numberOfNodes);

        for (var i = 0 ; i < possibleNextNodes.length ; i++) {
            currentRoute.push(possibleNextNodes[i]);
            generateRoutes(currentRoute, numberOfNodes, bestRoute, graphArray);
            currentRoute.splice(-1, 1); // remove the last element
        }
    }
}

function generateRangeWithoutUsed(used, numberOfNodes) {
    var rangeWithoutUsed = [];

    for (var i = 0 ; i < numberOfNodes ; i++) {
        if (!existInArray(i, used)) {
            rangeWithoutUsed.push(i);
        }
    }

    return rangeWithoutUsed;
}

function existInArray(element, array) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
        if (array[i] == element) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
var input = "Faerun to Norrath = 129\nFaerun to Tristram = 58\nFaerun to AlphaCentauri = 13\nFaerun to Arbre = 24\nFaerun to Snowdin = 60\nFaerun to Tambi = 71\nFaerun to Straylight = 67\nNorrath to Tristram = 142\nNorrath to AlphaCentauri = 15\nNorrath to Arbre = 135\nNorrath to Snowdin = 75\nNorrath to Tambi = 82\nNorrath to Straylight = 54\nTristram to AlphaCentauri = 118\nTristram to Arbre = 122\nTristram to Snowdin = 103\nTristram to Tambi = 49\nTristram to Straylight = 97\nAlphaCentauri to Arbre = 116\nAlphaCentauri to Snowdin = 12\nAlphaCentauri to Tambi = 18\nAlphaCentauri to Straylight = 91\nArbre to Snowdin = 129\nArbre to Tambi = 53\nArbre to Straylight = 40\nSnowdin to Tambi = 15\nSnowdin to Straylight = 99\nTambi to Straylight = 70";
// var myInput = "a to b = 1\na to c = 2\nb to d = 7\nc to d = 1\nc to e = 3\nd to f = 2\ne to f = 5";

var graphArray = generateGraphAsArray(input);
generateAllRoutes(graphArray.length, graphArray);
```

Comment: Objects (and by extensions, arrays) are passed by reference, meaning they are mutable. However, that only works if you modify the existing value, not reassign it. Your problem though is that the value at `graphArray[route[i]]` is `undefined`.

Comment: but believe me, it is not. I've put some console.log in those places, and only when I try to update the outer variable, it is undefined. This is quite weird because I've never changed the values in graphArray since its creation.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that the compiler/interpreter hasn't just broken for your case. There's something else you're missing. I'd dig into it myself but this is a lot of code and I'm at work.

Comment: thank you mate, when you can.

Comment: For what it's worth, [I just copied your code](https://jsfiddle.net/5k0b1Laq/) (and fixed your syntax error in the string at the bottom) and it seems to be running just fine.

Comment: This is only printing the total distance of each route, not getting the minimum cost route, that is what is intended

Comment: @MikeC now the code is updated to the "giving errors" version

Comment: In generateRoutes, if you else case happens, the function returns null (because there is no return statement), wicht sets bestRoute to null, wich causes an error the next time calculateCost gets called

Comment: @Neutrosider why don't you answer?? your comment gave me the insight I needed xD

Comment: i didn't know if this would be enough to solve your problem. Will answer it ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In generateRoutes, if your else case happens, the function returns null (because there is no return statement), wicht sets bestRoute to null, wich causes an error the next time calculateCost gets called